# Can not print out a set in Java

Tags: java, io

i am writing a program that read in two text files and find the differences
but for some reason, i can not print the result set. I checked for lot of times and still couldn't find the reason and i hope you guys can help me out. here is the code.

the problem occur at the for each to print the set.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class PartOne {


    public static void readFileAtPath(String filePathOne, String filePathTwo) {
        // Lets make sure the file path is not empty or null
        if (filePathOne == null || filePathOne.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid File Path");
            return;
        }

        if (filePathTwo == null || filePathTwo.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid File Path");
            return;
        }

        Set<String> newUser = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> oldUser = new HashSet<String>();

        BufferedReader inputStream = null;
        BufferedReader inputStream2 = null;
        // We need a try catch block so we can handle any potential IO errors
        try {
            // Try block so we can use ‘finally’ and close BufferedReader
            try {
                inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePathOne));
                inputStream2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePathTwo));

                String lineContent = null;
                String lineContent2 = null;

                // Loop will iterate over each line within the file.
                // It will stop when no new lines are found.
                while ((lineContent = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Here we have the content of each line.
                    // For now, I will print the content of the line.
                    // System.out.println("Found the line: " + lineContent);
                    oldUser.add(lineContent);
                }

                while ((lineContent2 = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    newUser.add(lineContent2);
                }

                Set<String> uniqueUsers = new HashSet<String>(newUser);
                uniqueUsers.removeAll(oldUser);

            }
            // Make sure we close the buffered reader.
            finally {
                if (inputStream != null)
                    inputStream.close();
                if (inputStream2 != null)
                    inputStream2.close();
            }


            for (String temp : uniqueUsers) {
                 System.out.println(temp);
             }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }// end of method

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath2 = "userListNew.txt";
        String filePath = "userListOld.txt";
        readFileAtPath(filePath, filePath2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try debugging your application.

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is scope.  You define the set inside your try block but then you attempt to access it from outside that block.  You must define all variables within the same scope you want to use that variable.

Move the definition of uniqueUsers to before your try block.

*Edit in response to your comment.

You are reading from the same input stream twice.  The second while loop should be reading from inputStream2.

Comment: thanks! and now i have another problem. It has succesfuly complied and run. but its printing nothing. it should print out the difference of two sets.

Comment: WoW another good catch! now the program is running prefectly fine! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 try {
    // Try block so we can use ‘finally’ and close BufferedReader
    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePathOne));
        inputStream2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePathTwo));

        String lineContent = null;
        String lineContent2 = null;

        // Loop will iterate over each line within the file.
        // It will stop when no new lines are found.
        while ((lineContent = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            // Here we have the content of each line.
            // For now, I will print the content of the line.
            // System.out.println("Found the line: " + lineContent);
            oldUser.add(lineContent);
        }

        while ((lineContent2 = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            newUser.add(lineContent2);
        }

        Set<String> uniqueUsers = new HashSet<String>(newUser);
        uniqueUsers.removeAll(oldUser);

        for (String temp : uniqueUsers) {
         System.out.println(temp);
        }

    }
    // Make sure we close the buffered reader.
    finally {
        if (inputStream != null)
            inputStream.close();
        if (inputStream2 != null)
            inputStream2.close();
    }        

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```